# How to see that this space with two vertices and four edges is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, intuition, homotopy-theory

I am having trouble seeing why this space has fundamental group $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z * \mathbb Z$.

I have read that this space is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$, from which we can conclude the fundamental groups are isomorphic.

How can I visualize this homotopy equivalence?

[image]

Comment: Collapse one of the edges to a point

Comment: @Max This would give us something like the Hawaiian earring but with only $3$ loops?

Comment: Visualising the homotopy inverse function is quite tricky. It's easier to see if you first think about the case of a figure eight ($S^1 \lor S^1$ which looks like $\infty$) and a circle plus a diameter (which looks like $\ominus$). The projectionof $\ominus$ onto $\infty$  that collapses the diameter is easy to visualise. The homotopy inverse identifies corresponding points on the edges of two small $v$-shapes at the centre of the figure eight (like closing a pair of scissors).

Comment: Your goal is to compute the fundamental group, right? So why don't you apply Van Kampen to the space and don't bother with transforming it to the wedge sum? You need Van Kampen anyway to compute the fundamental group of the wedge sum.

Comment: @freakish: I agree the question starts offf talking about fundamental groups but the OP is asking how to visualise the homotopy equivalence and van Kampen doesn't help with that.

Comment: @freakish I was trying this, but I could not find path-connected subsets which cover the space and whose intersection was also path-connected

Comment: A Hawaiian earring with $3$ loops (or any finite number of loops) is also called a bouquet of circles. For the fundamental group, do you know about the groupoid version of Van Kampen ?

Comment: @Max I am not familiar with the groupoid version. Just the version in Hatcher, Theorem 1.20.

Comment: @Wolfgang Take $U_1$ that contains edges $a,b,c$ and a bit of $d$ (near connection points). Take $U_2$ that contains edge $c, d$ and a bit of every other. Then the intersection is edge $c$ (with small pieces) which is contractible. Van Kampen applies. $U_2$ is a "sphere". And for $U_1$ apply Van Kampen again (now you have one edge less) in a similar manner.

Comment: If your question is not about how to visualise the homotopy equivalence but is about computing the fundamental groups, then it would be a kindness if you edited the question to save people wasting their time trying to help with the question you asked rather than the one that you intended to ask.

Comment: @RobArthan The title of the post is 'How to see that this space with two vertices and four edges is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$?' If I know that the space in question is homotopy equivalent to the wedge of three $S^1$'s, then I can deduce $\pi_1$ from this information.

Comment: @RobArthan I wrote in the post what I wanted this information for, but I didn't ask at all how to compute $\pi_1$.

Comment: @Wolfgang: OK. It looked from your comments that you were being sucked into help with calculating $\pi_1$ rather than visualising the homotopy equivalence. Did my original comment about $\infty$ and $\ominus$ help at all?

Comment: @RobArthan I see now. That analogy helps when I take one of the edges, say $a$, and try to make it straight, so it looks more like the theta space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see that the space in the figure, call it $X$, is homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$, use the first criteria for homotopy equivalence from Hatcher, page 11:

> If $(X,A)$ is a CW pair consisting of a CW complex $X$ and a contractible subcomplex $A$, then the quotient map $X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

The space in the figure, $X$, is a CW-complex, and the edge labeled $a$ is a subcomplex, call it $A$. So, $(X,A)$ is a CW pair. Also, the subcomplex $A$ is contractible. So, contracting $A$ to a point gives us a space, $X/A$, which is a wedge of three copies of $S^1$. Hence, by the criteria, $X$ and $X/A \cong S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$ are homotopy equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Juan's answer is probably best. But another way to visualize this is as follows.

Let $Y$ denote the space obtained by deleting three small disjoint discs from a bigger disc $D^2$. Embed your space $X$ into $Y$. Then there is a deformation retraction of $Y$ onto $X$. Similarly, you can get a deformation retraction of $Y$ onto the bouquet of three circles.